# Keras save model issue

Tags: save, deep-learning, keras

This is a variational autoencoder network, I have to define a sampling method to generate latent z, I thinks it might be something wrong with this. This py file is doing training, the other py file is doing predicting online, so I need to save the keras model, there is nothing wrong with saving model, but when I load model from 'h5' file, it shows an error:

```
NameError: name 'latent_dim' is not defined
```

The following is code:

```
df_test = df[df['label']==cluster_num].iloc[:,:data_num.shape[1]]

data_scale_ = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(df_test.values)

data_num_ = data_scale.transform(df_test.values)

models_deep_learning_scaler.append(data_scale_)

batch_size = data_num_.shape[0]//10

original_dim = data_num_.shape[1]

latent_dim = data_num_.shape[1]*2

intermediate_dim = data_num_.shape[1]*10

nb_epoch = 1

epsilon_std = 0.001



x = Input(shape=(original_dim,))

init_drop = Dropout(0.2, input_shape=(original_dim,))(x)

h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(init_drop)

z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)

z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(h)





def sampling(args):

    z_mean, z_log_var = args

    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(latent_dim,), mean=0.,

                              std=epsilon_std)

    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon



# note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])



# we instantiate these layers separately so as to reuse them later



decoder_h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')

decoder_mean = Dense(original_dim, activation='linear')

h_decoded = decoder_h(z)

x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)





def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):

    xent_loss = original_dim * objectives.mae(x, x_decoded_mean)

    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)

    return xent_loss + kl_loss



vae = Model(x, x_decoded_mean)

vae.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), loss=vae_loss)



train_ratio = 0.95

train_num = int(data_num_.shape[0]*train_ratio)



x_train = data_num_[:train_num,:]

x_test = data_num_[train_num:,:]



vae.fit(x_train, x_train,

        shuffle=True,

        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,

        batch_size=batch_size,

        validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

vae.save('./models/deep_learning_'+str(cluster_num)+'.h5')

del vae

from keras.models import load_model
vae = load_model('./models/deep_learning_'+str(cluster_num)+'.h5')
```

It shows error:
`NameError: name 'latent_dim' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For variational loss you are using many variable not known by Keras module. You need to pass them through `custom_objects` param of `load_model` function.

In your case:

```
vae.save('./vae_'+str(cluster_num)+'.h5')
vae.summary()

del vae

from keras.models import load_model
vae = load_model('./vae_'+str(cluster_num)+'.h5', custom_objects={'latent_dim': latent_dim, 'epsilon_std': epsilon_std, 'vae_loss': vae_loss})
vae.summary()
```

Comment: It works in the same py file, but it does not work if I create a new py file when loading h5 file from disk, the error is: 
NameError: name 'latent_dim' is not defined

Comment: Yes, `custom_objects` is just a dictionary..  in the new file those variables/functions don't exist. So you need to define them or pickle load them. Also since in the variational loss you need to use `z_mean` and `z_log_var` you may need to create part of the architecture again as pickle won't work.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out a lot

Comment: I have different error: ValueError: Error when checking model : the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0,...

Comment: @MarioZ its not a `load_model` error. Have commented on your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132099/save-and-load-keras-autoencoder)

Comment: @indraforyou But it should be the load_model connected error because it works fine with the model in memory.

Comment: @MarioZ .. not sure how you are making the model on memory work. The correct way to predict is to create the input for the `eps` input by `eps_inp = np.random.normal(0, epsilon_std, (original_dim, latent_dim))` and then use it for predict `vae_pred = autoencoder_disk.predict([x_test_encoded, esp_inp])`

Comment: You are right. Now it's working. Answer on my question to get some badges for your knowledge, kindness and patience. 

When I said 'when the model is in memory' I thought before saving/loading on a disk. Anyway, I still don't understand why I can predict without eps_inp before saving/loading model and need to use eps_inp in predict function after save/load model i.e. after loading from hard drive?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you load model (.h5) file in your new py file, you can use load_model('/.h5', compile = False).
Because you do not need to any custom objects (i.e loss function or latent_dim, etc) in prediction step.