# Save and load keras autoencoder

Tags: keras, autoencoder

Look at this strange load/save model situation. I saved variational autoencoder model and its encoder and decoder:

```py
autoencoder.save("autoencoder_save", overwrite=True)
encoder.save("encoder_save", overwrite=True)
decoder.save("decoder_save", overwrite=T)
```

After that I loaded all of it from the disk:

```py
autoencoder_disk = load_model("autoencoder_save", custom_objects={'KLDivergenceLayer': KLDivergenceLayer,
                                                       'nll': nll})
encoder_disk = load_model("encoder_save", custom_objects={'KLDivergenceLayer': KLDivergenceLayer,
                                                       'nll': nll})
decoder_disk = load_model("decoder_save", custom_objects={'KLDivergenceLayer': KLDivergenceLayer,
                                                       'nll': nll})
```

If I try

```py
x_test_encoded = encoder_disk.predict(x_test,batch_size=batch_size)
x_test_decoded = decoder_disk.predict(x_test_encoded)
print(np.round(x_test_decoded[3]))
```

Everything works just fine as if I use encoder/decoder from the memory, but if I try

```py
vae = autoencoder_disk.predict(x_test_encoded)
```

I got

```py
ValueError: Error when checking model : the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s) but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:...
```

although I can predict from the variational autoencoder from the memory. Why autoencoder does not work when it is loaded from the disk?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide reproducible code to understand how your models are defined. My guess is that `vae = autoencoder_disk.predict(x_test_encoded)`  should be `vae = autoencoder_disk.predict(x_test)`, since `x_test_encoded` seems to be the encoder's output.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be as you wrote. The models are defined just like in here: http://tiao.io/listings/vae/variational_autoencoder.py.html

Comment: acc to [line 72](http://tiao.io/listings/vae/variational_autoencoder.py.html#listingsvaevariational_autoencoderpy-72) of your code, `vae` needs a list with 2 input. You are only providing 1 input. Hence you are seeing the error.

Comment: I tried to put eps in custom:_objects like all other variables:
                                        custom_objects={'KLDivergenceLayer': KLDivergenceLayer, 'nll': nll, 'latent_dim': latent_dim, 'epsilon_std',                                       'eps':eps,'z':z
            
Unfortunately without success.
I also correct vae.predict() line to vae.predict(x_test)

Comment: THe point is that it works when I have the model in memory and it is not working when I load it.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the encoded output `x_test_encoded` as the input to the autoencoder `autoencoder_disk.predict(x_test_encoded)`. You should pass the original input the encoder expects `x_test` instead.

Comment: I'm so sorry because of misunderstanding. I mean that I wrote wrong in a question, not in my code.

Comment: The answer is in variables according to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754247/keras-save-model-issue?
Unfortunately I cannot find missed variable(s).